# FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 49430. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been working on a document based on google forms answers to calculate picture revisions.

This is the formula that I am trying to use: `=SORTN(FILTER('Raw Data'!G:G,'Raw Data'!C:C=B1,'Raw Data'!E:E,"No"),20,0)`

What I am trying to accomplish, is to pull 20 pictures per day of "bad parking". So I use 2 filters: bad parking and reviewed date. Yet it gives me an error saying there is a missmatch. I have reviewed the size and the reference is the full row. I have tried numbering the range (like G1:G99999) but nothing works. I am under the impression that the error is misleading me, I had the same issue in the array I am using to importrange the responses and I solved it by cutting the range into 3 pieces.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet I am working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fc3RbMwPCI2Txcy67WfqoPLDGPrUFF0JYuTMKEnXDFI/edit#gid=1067703029

Comment: Hey Alejandro Urbina Welcome to stackoverflow.com Ensure that you include a sample of a desired outcome in your question. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and Note that your (email addess name) is visible to anyone who accessed the sheet.

Comment: This question has many similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+FILTER+has+mismatched+range+sizes)

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
,"No"
```

to

```
="No"
```

---

```
=SORTN(FILTER('Raw Data'!G:G,'Raw Data'!C:C=B1,'Raw Data'!E:E="No"),20,0)
```